# Is the complement of the inversion relation (in the context of permutations) transitive?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm studying from [An Invitation to Discrete Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198570422) where I came upon an exercise which confuses me.

Let $\pi$ be a permutation of the set  $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$  and let $I(\pi)$ denote the set of all inversions, regarded as a relation on  $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ .

I can prove that this relation is transitive, but the book also asks me to prove that the complement of $I(\pi)$ is transitive. The trouble is... I can't prove it and it seems just false to me, as can be seen from this counterexample on the set $\{1,2,3\}$:
$$\pi_0=(1 \, 3\,2) $$
If we denote the inversion relation with $\rho$ and its complement with $\bar{\rho}$, we see:
$$2\,\bar{\rho}\,1 $$
because $2>1$ and $\pi_0(2) \nless \pi_0(1)$.

Similarly,
$$1\,\bar{\rho}\,3$$

If $\bar{\rho}$ is to be a transitive relation, shouldn't it be true that $2\,\bar{\rho}\,3$ ?

But $2<3$ and $\pi_0(2)>\pi_0(3)$ and that clearly means $2\,\rho\,3$... Am I missing something obvious here? (Must be something really obvious since I'm almost half-asleep! xD )

$$* * *$$

**P.S.** **Just in case I missed something, here's the original exercise, directly from the book**:
[image]

**ISSUE RESOLVED**: The author said that "it should not be the complement but probably the relation
$(i<j)$ and $(\pi(i)>\pi(j))$." It should be in the errata now.

Comment: Does $\pi_0$ here denote the permutation $1\mapsto 1,\ 2\mapsto 3,\ 3\mapsto 2$ (i.e. the transposition $(23)$), or  does it denote the *cycle* $(1\,3\,2)$ which maps $1\mapsto 3\mapsto 2\mapsto 1$?

Comment: I believe, a part of the detail is missing. $\bar{\rho}$ will be transitive if the relations $\rho$ and $\bar{\rho}$ are over the the ordered pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a<b$. If $\rho$ is defined as done in the problem, the complement gives "$j\le i$" OR "$\pi(i)\le \pi(j)$". This gives rise to possibilities like $2\bar{\rho}1$ (from the above example) and transitivity fails.

Comment: @Berci It denotes the first one, I just don't write the "top row".

Comment: @talegari Well, that's what I thought, but that's all there is, I didn't leave out any details, that's precisely what confuses me.

Comment: @ Squatting Erudite Would you mind sharing your proof for part a with me? I have trouble understanding hte proof as I have't studied relation yet.

Comment: Hey, no problem! :) You simply have to look at the definition of the relation in question. $a \rho b$ means that $a < b$ and $\pi (a) > \pi (b)$. So you just assume $a \rho b$ and $b \rho c$ for arbirtary $a, b, c$ and then it should be easy to see that indeed $a \rho c$, which proves transitivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as I can see, your analysis is correct, and the book is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your analysis looks fine to me too.

I looked here http://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~matousek/idm/ to see if this is among the errata, but it is not. You could write to the authors to signal this mistake.

Comment: I sent the mail, good idea! :)